# Why are Centennials called that?

Tags: meaning, etymology, grammatical-number, phrase-origin, roots

People of Generation Y have the nickname *millennials*, because many of them graduated around the year 2000, the millenium.

People of Generation Z are sometimes called *centennials*. "Centennial" means "100th anniversary," and I don't see how this generation has anything to do with the number 100.

Comment: Interestingly, when I first heard the term I had no idea it applied to me, I thought it was for the generation *born* around the new millennium. I am with you that calling the generation *after* millennial, "centennial", is very confusing.

Comment: I don't get it either, but then I'm a Baby Boomer so I've had it good all my life and don't care ;-) I also think smilies are meaningful :-( Not only that but I'm British so the worst of the Gen X,Y,Z stuff has passed me by. The really good thing is that that the people who invent this nonsense have now run out of letters and the turn of the Century/Millenium is almost 20 years ago so either they will have to be genuinely creatve for once or let their heads explode (and I _really_ don't care which they do).

Comment: If they had thought ahead, they would have started with Gen A.

Answer (score 1):

*Millennials* are named after the turn of the millennium, while *centennials* are named after the turn of the century (not a hundredth anniversary). As a matter of logic, a turn of the millennium is, at the same time, also a turn of the century. The most recent instances of both took place at exactly the same time. One would thus expect *millennials* and *centennials* to be different terms for the same people. The distinction between them was manufactured by naming the millennials after the time when they reached adulthood or developed towards it, and naming the centennials after the approximate time when they were born. There is no deep reason for the naming to have been done that way; it could have been done the other way round.

Such terms are typically created and pushed into circulation by those who write for the popular media, and who are more interested in whether the term sounds attention-grabbing than in whether its use is conducive to clarity and precision. They have thus chosen '*centennials* because it's a cool name, that references the already established name of *millennials*, not because it makes sense', as DJClayworth has earlier put it in the comments. Fortunately, at the moment, the term *centennials* does not yet seem to be well entrenched; those of us who do care about clarity and precision can thus still hope that it will  eventually fizzle out and be replaced by something else. *Generation Z* may be unimaginative, but it does have the advantage of not being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the following  extract “centennials” refer to century, in the sense that those who belong to the so called  Generation Z were born around the turn of the century, not to be confused with  millennials who were born mainly in the last two decades  of the second millennium:

> - ***[Millennial](http://inphantry.com/from-millennials-to-centennials-the-passing-of-the-torch/)***– According to Wikipedia, a millennial (also known as Gen Y) are the demographic cohort following Generation X. ***There are no precise dates when the generation starts and ends, but researchers and commentators use birth years ranging from the early 1980s to the early 2000s.***  Millennials are often up to date with new media tactics, and are shying away from the suburbs for more populated areas and searching often for quality over quantity in life, having children later and are focused on corporate responsibility.

while

> - ***Centennial*** – ***People who were born around the turn of the century. Mostly 13-18 year olds now***  Dubbed ‘Generation Z’ these permit holding youths are practical and value-conscious, who relish experiences and use the enormous amount of information at their disposal to unearth unique stories. Could be labeled as ‘needing’ technology to get through daily life.

From infantry.com

Comment: So 2001 is considered the turn of the century, not the millennium?

Comment: @PaulParker - 2001 is both the turn of the millennium and of the century , of course, but millennials  was a term already in use  for those born in the  ‘80s and ‘90s. Centennial refers  the following  generation, which, shows different characteristics  from the previous one.

Comment: So the point is that they are dubbed "Centennials" because it's a cool name, that references the already established name of "Millenials", not because it makes sense.

Comment: @DJClayworth, your comment is the only thing on this page that actually answers the question. Would you mind posting its as an answer, so that it can be voted on.